# Render an already rendered template

Tags: templates, meteor, render

I have a template who has already been rendered and another template with a checkbox in it.

```
<template name="first"> </template>

<template name="second">
   <input type="checkbox" checked="true" /> 
</template>
```

In Template.first.rendered, I have a if/else regarding the input. 
If the user check/uncheck the box, I have a listener to catch the event and I want to re-render the template "first" again from this event listener function.

I've been looking around, but I didn't find how to "call" the render function again...

Is that possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sessions for this:

```
<template name="first">
  {{#if updated}}
    if block
  {{else}}
    else block
  {{/if}}
</template>

Template.first.helpers({
  updated: function(){
    return Session.get('updated');
  }
});

<template name="second">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="true" /> 
</template>

Template.second.events({
  'click input': function(event, template){
    var x = template.$('input').is(":checked");
    Session.set("updated", x);
  }
});
```

Here is a [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/mtAEtTL4FqhySWoH9/Render%20an%20already%20rendered%20template):